# Xamarin.Forms Vidyo.IO "OnLocalCameraStateUpdated" (Connector.IRegisterLocalCameraEventListener) callback not called

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webrtc, vidyo

I need help regarding vidyo.io SDK in xamarin. I code based on the provided github repo for sample purpose. My problem is i cant see the camera preview in my custom renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find RefreshUI() method inside VidyoController.cs and add:

```
   _connector.AssignViewToCompositeRenderer(_videoView.Handle, Connector.ConnectorViewStyle.ConnectorviewstyleDefault, 15);
```

Before _connector.ShowViewAt(....);
It will reassign your view as display a preview