# Image not showing on Vidyo call on Safari (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, safari, videochat, vidyo

Im trying to make browser based app used mainly on mobile devices that in one part uses Vidyo as videochat host. When i join conversation on iphone (safari) it detects camera but does not show image (not even preview of me is shown). Voice is working.

Im using their example code but forwarding all users to browserbased chat.

Comment: Please share the code you are using

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933714/xamarin-forms-vidyo-io-onlocalcamerastateupdated-connector-iregisterlocalcame/51479208#51479208

Comment: Im using html + JavaScript so that doesn't help :(  Code is basically what they provide as sample javacript.

Answer (score 0):

Vidyo is not officially supported on mobile browsers, especially on iOS Safari.
However, Native WebRTC should work with mobile browsers but it is still on beta for Safari.

To know more about how to use Native WebRTC, please refer to the following article: https://support.vidyo.io/hc/en-us/articles/360005898574-Native-WebRTC-Support